# Elasticsearch pipeline can't access @myfield

Tags: elasticsearch

On a document creation I would like to access to a field which starts with '@'.

**Document will be added this way:**

```
POST http://localhost:9200/myindex/_doc?pipeline=test_pipeline
{
"name":"Joe",
"@myfield":"field value"
}
```

Can't even add a pipeline like this, it throws a compile error (using the field without the '@' works well)

```
{
    "description": "describe pipeline",
    "processors": [
        {
            "script": {
                "ignore_failure": false,
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "ctx._id= ctx.@myfield"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Trying the solution described here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-how-to-access-timestamp-field-in-script/130263

```
{
    "description": "describe pipeline",
    "processors": [
        {
            "script": {
                "ignore_failure": false,
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "ctx._id= ctx._source['@myfield']"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This creates the pipeline successfully, however adding the document the way described above won't succeed, throws an NPE:

```
 "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
            "ctx._id= ctx._source['@myfield']",
            "            ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "ctx._id= ctx._source['@myfield']",
        "lang": "painless",
        "position": {
            "offset": 12,
            "start": 0,
            "end": 34
        },
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot invoke \"Object.getClass()\" because \"callArgs[0]\" is null"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works : `"source": "ctx._id= ctx['@myfield']"`

ctx._source  can be accessed only when using update, update-by-query, or reindex API 
**source:**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html